# "Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once; existing SparkContext(app=dataHudi, master=local[*]) created by getOrCreate at

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

when trying to create multiple spark sessions (because of multiple api hits): I am getting error "Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once; existing SparkContext(app=dataXXXX, master=local[*]) created by getOrCreate at".

So can someone please help me to understand why it is happening? how to handle multiple requests simultaneously

I tried the below code but this is not solving the issue

```
            flag = False
            spark=None
            while not flag:
                sparksessioncreator_object = NewSparkSession()
                spark = sparksessioncreator_object.Create_Session()
                if (spark.getActiveSession()):
                    print('ActiveSession yes')
                    flag = True
                else:
                    try:
                        spark.stop()
                    except:
                        pass
                    finally:
                        print('ActiveSession no')
```

Also, This is for your reference.

class NewSparkSession:

#..................................,..........................................................................................

```
def __init__(self):
    print("Creating Spark Session ------------------------>")
```

#..................................,..........................................................................................

```
def Create_Session(self):
    
    
    spark = SparkSession.builder \
            .master("local[*]") \
            .appName("dataHudi") \
            .config('spark.driver.bindAddress', '0.0.0.0') \
            .config('spark.driver.host', 'localhost') \
            .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.hudi:hudi-spark3.3-bundle_2.12:0.13.1') \
            .config('spark.serializer', 'org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer') \
            .config('spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog', 'org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.catalog.HoodieCatalog') \
            .config('spark.sql.extensions', 'org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.HoodieSparkSessionExtension') \
            .getOrCreate()
    
    
    return spark
```

Comment: Are you trying to use `SparkSession.newSession()` method to create the Spark Session? If 
you are trying to stop the Spark context - don't do that instead stop and start spark sessions from a `masterSession`.  If that is the use case, then check my answer as well.

Comment: Hi @Lingesh.K thanks for your reference, However I have update my code through edit so I think you can get the proper knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with Spark is that it is designed to a single `SparkContext` per JVM. A `SparkContext` is the basic connection that is established to work with the spark objects in the cluster. The `SparkSession` object is the entry point to the application and ideally it can be used to share the same configuration across multiple applications.

However, I have made changes to the class such that you can keep actively creating new sessions once a base session object is created.

```py
class NewSparkSession:
    def __init__(self, base_session):
        self.base_session = base_session
        print("Creating New Spark Session ------------------------>")

    def create_session(self):
        # Create a new session with isolated SQL configurations
        spark_session = self.base_session.newSession()

        return spark_session
```

This class `NewSparkSession` now has a `__init__` method which is used to set the `base_session` variable which will be used to derive new sessions as the loop construct progresses in your calling method.

In the calling method, you can add this change:

```py
import pyspark.sql


# Create a base SparkSession
# Set configurations for the session which will be common throughout the execution
base_session = (pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder
                .master("local[*]")
                .appName("dataHudi")
                .config('spark.driver.bindAddress', '0.0.0.0')
                .config('spark.driver.host', 'localhost')
                .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.hudi:hudi-spark3.3-bundle_2.12:0.13.1')
                .config('spark.serializer', 'org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer')
                .config('spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog', 'org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.catalog.HoodieCatalog')
                .config('spark.sql.extensions', 'org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.HoodieSparkSessionExtension')
                .getOrCreate())

flag = False
new_spark_session = None
while not flag:
    spark_session_creator_object = NewSparkSession(base_session)
    new_spark_session = spark_session_creator_object.create_session()
    if new_spark_session:
        print("New Spark Session is active")
        # Create any new spark config elements as it will be needed for each iteration of the while loop
        new_spark_session.conf.set("key", "value") # etc..
        # Use the new_spark_session to drive some logic
        print(new_spark_session) # New Spark Session derived from base session object
        flag = True
    else:
        try:
            new_spark_session.stop()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}\n")
        finally:
            print("No Spark Sessions are active now")
```

I have added a `base_session` object which can be used as a basis to create multiple spark sessions and drive the process per session and stop once you have addressed the API calls made.

Not sure of the need of `if..else` block you have used, but instead of just checking on the state of the `new_spark_session` object, you can add an iterator variable to drive until there are API hits and stop if not.